# Wildcard in Generics doesn't work

Tags: java, generics

Looking at the following code, why doesn't the second invocation of dump get compiled? And how can I fix it without removing the wildcard?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Column<A, T extends Object> {
}

public class Generics {

  static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer i = 5;

    // this works
    List<Column<Integer, ?>> columns1 = new ArrayList<Column<Integer, ?>>();
    dump(columns1, i);

    // this doesn't
    List<Column<Integer, String>> columns2 = new ArrayList<Column<Integer, String>>();
    dump(columns2, i);
  }

  static <A, T> void dump(Iterable<Column<A, ?>> columns, A value) {
    for (Column<A,?> col: columns) {
      System.out.println(col);
    }
  }

}
```

The JDK's compiler gives

```
Generics.java:18: <A,T>dump(java.lang.Iterable<Column<A,?>>,A) in Generics cannot be applied to (java.util.List<Column<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String>>,java.lang.Integer)
 dump(columns2, i);

    ^
1 error
```

Comment: I'd just like to add, that **T** type declaration in method dump is actually not needed at all, and has nothing to do with the class-level **T**, declared for Column class.

Comment: Oh yes. I compiled this as a minimal working example when still in office. Have to check whether this flaw exists in the original code too. Thank you.

Comment: It turned out the T declaration was a leftover that isn't used any more in the original code either. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `columns` in `dump()` acts as a producer of objects, you need to declare it with `extends` (the general rule is "producer - `extends`, consumer - `super`"):

```
static <A, T> void dump(Iterable<? extends Column<A, ?>> columns, A value) {
    for (Column<A,?> col: columns) {
        System.out.println(col);
    }
}
```